# how to wait for the subscribe event to finish before routing

Tags: angular, http, post, routes, rxjs

I'm currently doing a POST method and routing my application with some params but the problem seems to be that application routes before the POST method is completed and comes bk with a response.

my function:

```
    let responseBody;

    let postUploads = function() {
      return this.http.post(url, uploadFile).pipe((response: any) => this.responseBody = response);
    }

    postUploads().subscribe(() => this.router(['/inbox], { queryParams: {file: responseBody} }));
```

the issue that is happening is that it goes to the route before the "responseBody" is returned as a response from the POST

how do i make it wait for the response to come back before i route the user?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here.

```js
let responseBody;

let postUploads = function() {
  return this.http.post(url, uploadFile).pipe((response: any) => this.responseBody = response);
}
```

In this code, because you are declaring a function using `function() { }` syntax, `this` will reference the function itself. `this.http` will be undefined.

Also, it looks like you are attempting to set the local variable `responseBody` with the expression `this.responseBody = response`.

It is also an incorrect use of `pipe`. Pipe accepts RxJS operators, such as `map`, `tap`, etc. It doesn't accept a callback like this.

```js
this.router(['/inbox], { queryParams: {file: responseBody} })
```

In this code you are not calling the router in a correct way. I suspect you mean `this.router.navigate(['/inbox], { queryParams: {file: responseBody} })`;

#### The fixed version

Your code can be simplified to the following:

```js
this.http.post(url, uploadFile).subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.router.navigate(['/inbox'], { queryParams: {file: response } });
});
```

This subscribes to the observable and performs navigation when the response is received. I don't know what data type `response` is, but if it's some kind of blob, you probably don't want to put it in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the wrong `responseBody`.

Try this instead:

```
  this.http.post(url, uploadFile)
    .subscribe(responseBody => this.router(['/inbox'], { queryParams: { file: responseBody } }))
```

The idea is to let the output of observable (e.g. `http.post()`) flow through the observable chain.

Comment: hmm this method doesnt work either...so the route changes first with responseBody with no response, and goes through it again a second time with the response attached.

Answer (score 0):

I think local variable responseBody is unnecessary here. You can directly get the reference of responseBody inside the subscribe method. I have removed the unnecessary code, please check and let me know if it works.

```
    let postUploads = function() {
      return this.http.post(url, uploadFile);
    }

    postUploads().subscribe((responseBody) => this.router(['/inbox], { queryParams: {file: responseBody} }));
```